# how to locate a object in the system tree in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

In powerbuilder, I open a window or a datawindow from the Library. How can I locate the window or the datawindow in the system tree? The target has many pbls and objects. To find one is difficult.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

PBSearch can find what library an object is in. It also has advanced string search, search and replace, stored procedure search, and other features.

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/pbsearch.html